# Change current position of WearableListView

Tags: android, wear-os

Standart `ListView` have [SetSelection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection(int)). But I don't see this method for `WearableListView`.

How I can change centered item at WearableListView?

SOLUTION:
Thanks @pskink: scrollToPosition(int position) / smoothScrollToPosition(int position)

Comment: see scrollToPosition(int position) / smoothScrollToPosition(int position)

Comment: @pskink, thanks. Strangely, at first I try find any method at wearable-1.0.0-javadoc\WearableListView.html and nothing found...

Comment: Oh, my bad, this method exists in RecyclerView.